# Gitlab Multi Repo Multi Pipeline how to do it correctly

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, cicd

Rephrasing with more details:

I have repo A, which includes branch dev, uat, live. At this repo there is a big gitlab-ci.yml file, with a lot .env and Dockerfiles each for a client,  there are 2 stages at each branch for each client, one stage is the build and the other is the deploy.

What I want to achieve is for Repo A to exclude the .env files and Dockerfiles to another repo, let's call it Repo B, and at repo A the gitlab-ci.yml file will only include a trigger mechanism to repo B.

So at repo B there will exist the .env files the Docker files and all the pipeline stages from repo A will go to repo B.

When someone makes a change at repo A for branch dev for X client this will trigger the pipeline from repo B for the same branch for the same client and so on.

I hope that this is more clear.

Thank you again in advance! :-D

Comment: The problem is not very clear to me. `I want to create repo B that will use the code files from repo A` does cloning repo A from repo B pipeline work for this? `pipeline that does not fit anymore` what do you mean by this? `e.g. repo A branch dev with commit tag to trigger the pipeline from repo B using the commit tag from repo A.` -- this sounds like what you described that you already have in the first sentence of that paragraph. Could you try rephrasing your question or adding more detail to be more clear about the problem?